# R - Subtracting most recent data from oldest

Tags: r, database

So the current dataframe I'm working with has the following format:

```
ID Date       D1
1  2011-07-03 5
1  2012-04-05 6
1  2015-02-06 7
2  2010-08-21 4
2  2011-06-06 2
3  2016-05-20 5
3  2010-03-10 10
```

Where ID is a unique ID. I want to be able to subtract D1 from the most recent date by D1 from the oldest date for each set of ID.

I'd then want to divide the result by the #Years between the oldest and newest date. Is this possible?

UPDATE:

Hi all. I put in this code:

```
z <- y %>%      
 arrange(y$ID, y$Date) %>%
 group_by(y$ID) %>% 
 summarise(Diff = first(y$D1) - last(y$D1),
        nyears = year(last(y$Date)) - year(first(y$Date)))
```

However the data being returned is:

```
ID  Diff nyears
 0  1.12     27
 1  1.12     27
 2  1.12     27
 3  1.12     27
 4  1.12     27
 5  1.12     27
 6  1.12     27
 8  1.12     27
 9  1.12     27
13  1.12     27
```

The numbers seem incredibly inaccurate, and the results are repeating themselves. How can I resolve this? Ideally. I would like my output to simply be that the differences are calculated based on the difference in D1 given a unique ID:

```
ID  Diff 
 0  1.12     
 1  0.32     
 2  3.2
```

etc.

Comment: Update your example with expected output.

Comment: try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(Date) %>% summarise(Diff = first(D1) - last(D1), years = year(first(Date)) - year(last(Date)))`

Comment: Sample data and desired output are not in sync. You need to correct it and I would also suggest to share input data using `dput(y)`. BTW for this new requirement you simply need to modify @akrun's solution as `summarise(Diff = (last(D1) - first(D1))/lubridate::time_length(difftime(last(Date), first(Date)), "years"))`.

Comment: The output is still printing the same Diff regardless of the ID, just with a different number (Which is the difference between the value at the top of the sheet and the value at the bottom, and dividing it by their corresponding years). I don't understand why the results are repeating.

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'ID', `arrange` by 'Date', then get the difference of the `last` and the `first` 'D1', and also do the difference of the `year` between the corresponding 'Date' elements.  (Assuming that the 'Date' is `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%      
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Diff = first(D1) - last(D1),
            nyears = year(last(Date)) - year(first(Date)))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much. It seems to be working, but this error is popping up when I want to make it a column: "Replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]."

Comment: Just managed to overcome that, but the results I've gotten for the different are all identical.

Comment: @Ayfex  Not clear about your comment.  Did you use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

Comment: I used summarise, however the results came out as such:


`ID Difference   Years


1     4.4              NA


2     4.4              NA


3     4.4              NA


4     4.4              NA`


In other words, the difference calculated for D1 are all the same

Comment: @Ayfex May be the `summarise` got masked by `plyr::summarise` if both dplyr and plyr are loaded.  You can do this on a fresh session with only dplyr loaded or use `%>% dplyr::summarise(Diff = first(D1) -`